# Angular 4-5 HttpClient strong typing of http get

Tags: angular, typescript

I use a helper service that simplifies httpClient calls. I would like to strongly type the Observable that is returned.

my service where I use the api Service and try to get a strongly typed observable that emits >.

```js
export class ApiUser(){
  constructor(private api: Api){}

  getUsers(url? : string): Observable<Array<User>>{
    return this.api.get<Array<User>>('users'); //here I get errors on types.
  }
}
```

my api helper service, where the type should be passed :

```js
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
    import {User} from "../../interfaces/interfaces";

    /**
     * Api is a generic REST Api handler.
     */
    @Injectable()
    export class ApiService {
      constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

      get(endpoint: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any){
       
        return this.http.get('https://sub.domain.com/api/v1/' + 
     endpoint,reqOpts);
      }
    }
```

So the issue is that this is likely not the right way to strongly type, it works if I type on `this.http.get` inside the api helper service, but that defeats the purpose of having a helper service.

Comment: can you post `this.api.get` method?

Comment: It just wont compile the typescript as my method would not return the proper type for my controllers to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a [*type variable*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to your `ApiService.get` function, because `HttpClient.get` assumes a standard `Object` when a type is not provided. In order to do that, you can update `ApiService.get` to use such a type variable (e.g. `T`), like so:

```
get<T>(endpoint: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.get<T>('https://sub.domain.com/api/v1/' + 
         endpoint,reqOpts);
}
```

Note you specify `<T>` both as part of the function declaration (`get<T>`) and as the parameter being passed into `HttpClient.get`.

Comment: You made my day! The method that uses the api get method needs `<Observable<HttpEvent<T>>` is there a way to turn it into <Observable<T>> ? right now it looks like `public getUser(id : string): Observable<HttpEvent<{result : User}>>{
    return this.api.get<{result : User}>(this.url + `users/${id}`);
  }
`